# Saving data-attributes in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to loop through a page of

and store every

with the data attribute of "agencyname". Although, my JQuery code doesnt allow me to do so. Can someone take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong, thanks.

**The HTML**
    
            
              
                First

**The Jquery:**

```
var myVals = [];
$('a').data('agencyname').map(function(){
  myVals.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Comment: Please provide your html part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using attribute selectors.

```
var myVals = $('a[data-agencyname]').map(function(){
 return $(this).data('agencyname');
}).get();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/7ENZL/)

Comment: Thanks Anton, it looks like I was way off. But this worked for me